# Check_mk cannot login - invalid credentials

Tags: check-mk, omdistro

I've installed omd 2.90-labs-edition. After creating new site I want to login to check_mk (1.2.8.p20) web interface, but the given credentials do not work, I've got "Invalid credentials". This credentials only work for thruk web interface.

Here's output for creating a new site:

```
Adding /omd/sites/test/tmp to /etc/fstab.
Creating temporary filesystem /omd/sites/test/tmp...OK
Apache port 5000 is in use. I've choosen 5001 instead.
Restarting Apache...OK
Created new site test with version 2.90-labs-edition.

The site can be started with omd start test.
The default web UI is available at https://servername/test/

The admin user for the web applications is omdadmin with password: password
(It can be changed with the 'set_admin_password' command as site user.)

Please do a su - test for administration of this site.
```

New site is started, but login page for https://server_address/test/check_mk/login.py only gives me "invalid credentials" after login to "omdadmin" user.

Can't find the reason why... no information in logs /omd/sites/test/var/log/apache/error_log

Unfortunately tip about changing initial credentials for omdadmin user from https://mathias-kettner.com/check_mk-werks.php?werk_id=7643&__hstc=14126696.95407ad675cb255879d5c9f0e7607474.1553259391987.1553519829997.1553598167959.3&__hssc=14126696.1.1553598167959&__hsfp=3878063914 doesn't work for me or I do something wrong...

How to login to check_mk webinterface? Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions was to turn off thruk_cookie_auth (omd config -> Web GUI).