# Checkmk 1.6.0p21 can't login even after resetting password - Invalid credentials

Tags: htpasswd, check-mk

I'm unable to log into a Checkmk 1.6.0p21 dashboard through the web interface. I have access to the machine running it and nothing I do on it makes a difference.
It always gives the error "Invalid credentials." with no further explanation or anything in the logs.

I found this post on ServerFault too [Check_mk cannot login - invalid credentials](https://serverfault.com/questions/959852/check-mk-cannot-login-invalid-credentials), however this variable in the answers doesn't seem to exist in 1.6.0p21 anymore.

I'm considering upgrading to a few patches higher, however we have many Checkmk servers running with Livestatus, so we can't deviate from this version too much or else it could break the distributed monitoring.

I've reset the password with htpasswd and it changes the file just fine, the wato/users.mk file gets changed, the account isn't locked, the file permissions are okay.

I've ran out of ideas on what to check, has anyone encountered this issue and could assist in fixing it?

Comment: Update: Creating and restoring a backup on a different host has the problem persist. So it has to be a configuration error somewhere.

Comment: Did you try to use another browser? I saw the issue sometimes, that a browser was the actual culprit.

Comment: Yeah I have, and many colleagues tried it too.

I'm thinking it's an error in the site config in distributed monitoring, something with syncing users might be preventing logins while not working with synced users either. Although after changing options here (Like disabling syncing) it didn't help.

We're probably going to reinstall the site and push the config again from the central site next week. I've had like 10 people look at it and no one knew, so we're not going to waste any more time on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me say this up front: You are running the old stable release and not even the latest patch release, so I have to encourage you to upgrade rather earlier that later. Ideally to 2.0 as 2.1 is about to drop.

Now to your situation: It sounds, like you are running a distributed setup, although your question never states that. The problem seems to be, that you cannot log into a remote site, while the central site is working fine, presumably. It sounds like you are running the managed services edition, where you have the customer attribute. If my assumptions are true, take a closer look at the customer attribute of the affected users. Only users, that are assigned to the customer of the site or to the global customer can log into the specific site.

If my assumptions are wrong, and you are running the RAW edition, you might want to log at the sites web.log, or ask in the [Checkmk commmunity](https://forum.checkmk.com), there might be someone familiar with your problem.

Comment: You were totally right! I updated to the latest patch but that didn't make a difference. We are planning an upgrade to 2.1 within the coming months.
Indeed we are running the managed servives edition.

I tried giving the customer attribute and it worked, thank you so so much! I wish it gave an error literally anywhere but it works now!

Comment: It is kind of a classic with the managed services edition if you had no training on the product. And even if, this is something that is often missed, while a more distinct message is not possible, due to the inner mechanics of the authentication.